# Python Flask avro request issue

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I am sending a avro file as binary data to a flask application. The flask application is running in a container with python 3.6.
When I use the image in my local environment is working fine. I am getting the proper response. But when I deploy the image to kubernates, for some weird reason I am not able to decode the avro payload. Not sure what is related to the encode or the SO running the container.

For send the data I am using the following curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://foo/endpoint' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/avro;charset=UTF-8' \
--header 'Accept: application/avro+json' \
--data-binary '@c:/blabla/file.avro'
```

In my flask application I am receiving the request as:

```
@application.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def get_attributes_response(foo):
    res= request.get_data()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: when I get the avro binary data in the flask app, I am not able to serialize the object. For some reason its get corrupted